# AirPods Poor Siri Voice Quality

Tags: airpods

I recently purchased Apple AirPods, which I use with my iPhone 7. The sound quality is amazing, however, when using Siri through the AirPods, whether invoked on the iPhone or double-tapping the AirPod, Siri's voice quality is very poor. It does not sound too unlike the original low-quality Siri voice you get on a new iMac or iPhone before it downloads the HD version. When I disconnect the AirPods, Siri goes back to speaking in her high quality voice, with the context inflections Apple added not long ago. Is there any way to switch the voice quality for the AirPods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is abnormal behavior. Siri functions normally on my Airpods. I would try resetting them.

[How to Factory Reset AirPods](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/quick-tip/factory-reset-apple-airpods-may-help-battery-pairing-issues/) (see link for images)

1. Put your AirPods in their case—keep the lid open
2. Hold the button on the back, as shown above, for three to five seconds until the amber light blinks three times
3. Close the lid
4. On your iPhone, go to Settings > Bluetooth > AirPods and Forget This Device, as shown below

Comment: I would also be curious to see what happens if you change the voice to say a male voice within settings -> Siri. Does that catch on the airpods? Maybe switching back to female could help.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't such things like upgrading the voice quality available right now as far as I know. If that seems to be an issue, you should visit an Apple Store while it's in the warranty time period.